# Neo4J Cypher query creates multiple nodes when IN clause is defined in query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am seeing a really strange problem that the Cypher query is creating multiple nodes when I run the following query and the number of nodes created depends on the how many elements are defined in the IN clause of the query

```
MATCH (shipper:Shipper)-[:SHIPS_PRODUCT_TYPE]->(prodType:ProductType) 
WHERE shipper.InternalId = 1
AND prodType.InternalId IN [11,3,1]
CREATE (load:Shipment {
      InternalId: 5,
      NodeType: "Shipment",
      Created: "2013-11-24T18:25:12.3179997+05:30",
      Modified: "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"})
RETURN distinct load AS load, shipper AS shipper
```

I expect that this query only returns one row of data, but is returning 3 rows as its **creating 3 "load:Shipment"** nodes with the same data

Am i missing something on how this IN clause has to be used, as I don't even use the match in my create statements for this example?

**EDIT**

BTW I forgot to mention that I also tried to introduce the With statement as below even then I ended up with multiple nodes

```
MATCH (shipper:Shipper)-[:SHIPS_PRODUCT_TYPE]->(prodType:ProductType) 
WHERE shipper.InternalId = 1
AND prodType.InternalId IN [11,3,1]
WITH shipper, prodType
CREATE (shipper)-[:HAS_PUBLISHED]->(load:Shipment {
      InternalId: 5,
      NodeType: "Shipment",
      Created: "2013-11-24T18:25:12.3179997+05:30",
      Modified: "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"})-[:CONTAINS_PRODUCT]->(prodType)
RETURN distinct load AS load, shipper AS shipper
```

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really have to do with IN. You are matching more than one result from your initial MATCH/WHERE, so it's creating a node for each result. From the example, I'm not even sure why you're making the initial query, since it's not used in the second part at all. I imagine you mean to connect your new node via a relationship? Maybe you should check out the MERGE command in RC1, which lets you "MATCH or CREATE" a node or a relationship.

Update:

You probably want to use CREATE UNIQUE or MERGE instead of just CREATE, to avoid duplicate nodes. Maybe something like this:

```
MATCH (shipper:Shipper)-[:SHIPS_PRODUCT_TYPE]->(prodType:ProductType) 
WHERE shipper.InternalId = 1
AND prodType.InternalId IN [11,3,1]
WITH shipper, prodType
CREATE UNIQUE (shipper)-[:HAS_PUBLISHED]->(load:Shipment {
    InternalId: 5,
    NodeType: "Shipment",
    Created: "2013-11-24T18:25:12.3179997+05:30",
    Modified: "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"})
WITH shipper, load, prodType
CREATE UNIQUE (load)-[:CONTAINS_PRODUCT]->(prodType)
RETURN distinct load AS load, shipper AS shipper
```

Comment: I just extracted this from my much larger query, that's the reason this does not really show the intent. what I was trying to do was to first filter and get the required nodes and then create a new node and later create the association with the newly created node with the other nodes. I also tried to use with statement between the match and create, even then I ended up with the same result. Could you pls help me understand whats really happening in this case, does it execute create for every match path?

Comment: In that case how would one write a query to achieve what I was trying. i.e. I have a Shipper and bunch of products they handle, and when they publish a load, they provide the products in the shipment. in my edit above I was trying to fetch the shipper and the product and then try and associate it with the the new shipment i am creating.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I think I get it now. but this might be an issue for some of the larger queries to create multiple associations in one query. Hope there was a simple way to chain the query results and break the implicit foreach.